# Solving a differential equation modeling 2D convection

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, boundary-condition-at-infinity

How can

$\qquad  a_2\nabla^2 f(r,\theta) - \vec{g} \cdot \nabla f(r,\theta)= 0$

be solved for $f$? There is a symmetry in $\phi$ in spherical coordinates, so the equation is a 2D equation (depends on $r$ and $\theta$ which is angle with $z$ axis).

$\vec{g}$ is definded as below:

$\qquad  g_\theta(r,\theta) = \sin \theta (1-\frac{\sin \theta }{2 r^2})-\frac{\alpha \sin ^2 \theta \cos \theta}{r^4}$

$\qquad  g_r(r,\theta) = \cos \theta (-1+\frac{1}{ r^3})+\frac{3\alpha}{2r^2}(\frac{1}{r^2}-1)(\cos^2 \theta-\frac{1}{3})$

Boundary conditions are:

$\qquad  \partial_r f(r=1,\theta)= -a_3$

$\qquad  f(r=\infty,\theta)= a_1$

$a_1, a_2, a_3,\alpha$ are defined constants for example 10000 ,0.5,1,1 , respectively.

Could anyone please help me?

$\theta$ changes from $0$ to $2 \pi$ and boundary condition doesn't depend on it.

Comment: And what is $\alpha$?

Comment: It is also a coefficient. I add its value. Thank you for pointing out that. @m_goldberg

Comment: Is it possible to solve it using Mathematica? @m_goldberg

Comment: What have you tried? Since the equation is linear, `"FiniteElement"` method of `NDSolve` should be able to handle the problem without (much) difficulty.

Comment: The problems are boundary conditions and  think it could be upossible to solve it by mathematica. @xzczd

Comment: If you mean the boundary condition at infinity, using a far enough position as an approximation is enough in many cases. (There exist advanced techniques of course, you may check [questions tagged with _boundary-condition-at-infinity_](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boundary-condition-at-infinity).) BTW, you don't give b.c. for $\theta$ but I guess it's periodic b.c.? Then we also have `PeriodicBoundaryCondition`.

Comment: $\theta$ changes from $0$ to $2 \pi$ and boundary condition doesn't depend on it.  @xzczd

Comment: I mean, you've only given 2 b.c. in $r$ direction, but you still need b.c. in $\theta$ direction. (usually it's periodic b.c.)

Comment: $\theta$ is bounded and can not be more than $\pi$ @xzczd

Comment: That's the _range_ of $\theta$, not the boundary condition (b.c.) in $\theta$ direction, which is necessary for determing a particular solution, because your equation involves derivative of $\theta$.

Comment: Yes it is periodic @xzczd

Comment: What should I do to get some answers? @xzczd

Comment: Would you please help me? @xzczd

Comment: Which part do you have difficulty in coding?

Comment: All of it, mostly Delta function. @xzczd

Comment: That's not a problem at all, because you're solving the equation in $r\in [1, \infty)$, so it's just $0$. As mentioned above, `NDSolve` should handle your problem without (much) difficulty, what have you tried?

Comment: It is easy for you to use NDSolve, not for me @xzczd